# Ledger Nano S backup phrase + Mnemonic code converter test

Tags: private-key, backup, ledger-nano-s

So, I just tried testing my backup phrase offline on this page:

https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/

I typed in my 24 word backup phrase in the BIP39 mnemonic field and set the coin box to Ethereum.

Should the first generated address (m/44'/60'/0'/0/0) match my first public ledger address? Because they don't.

My Ledger is still working so I still have access to my Ether but I want to make sure my 24 word phrase is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retested it on

https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction

using "Mnemonic phrase". Here you can choose a different address path and it says which one is used by what type of device.

It turns out Ledgers use m/44'/60'/0' instead of m/44'/60'/0'0/0, so my phrase was correct. It seems that currently the Coleman BIP39 tool doesn't support m/44'/60'/0' paths.